# ASP.NET MVC open file in new window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I create a MVC Web application. 
I need to open the pdf file when user clicks the 'View' button on the page. 
The filepath where the pdf is stored is read from the database and it is a file on c: How do I open it in my code?

I have this code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Read", "ViewOnline", new { controller = "Home", id = item.Id }, new { target = "_blank" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

And my Controller

```
public ActionResult ViewOnline(int id)
{
  string link = BookBUS.Instance.GetBooks().Find(x => x.BookID == id).FilePath;
  if (link != null)
  {
    TempData["Embed"] = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(link);
  }
}
```

Comment: Error "too many characters in character literal"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating two separate objects for HTML attributes:

```
new { target = "_blank" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" }
```

I'm not even sure what overload of the `ActionLink` method that would invoke.  But one thing's for certain, both of these separate method parameters won't be combined internally for the HTML attributes.

Create one object for the HTML attributes:

```
new { target = "_blank", @class = "btn btn-default" }
```

Which should then be using [the correct method overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29).